# $\frac{x}{y} \ge \frac{a_1}{b_1} \ge \frac{a_2}{b_2}$ and $b_1 \le b_2 \implies \frac{x+a_1}{y + b_1} \ge \frac{x+a_2}{y + b_2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions

Given 
$\frac{x}{y} \ge \frac{a_1}{b_1}  \ge \frac{a_2}{b_2}$, where $x,y,a_i,b_i$ are positive numbers.

I would like to prove the following:

**Claim:** 
If $b_1 \le b_2$, then $\frac{x+a_1}{y + b_1} \ge \frac{x+a_2}{y + b_2}$.

Comment: The freshman sum is an order-preserving operation, which will help you prove this statement.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. Would you please give me some reference for freshman sum? Google isn't helping much.

Comment: It is also known as the mediant in more formal settings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)

Comment: Thank you Ryan. I think they prove $\frac{x}{y} \ge \frac{a_1 + a_2}{b_1+ b_2} \ge \frac{a_2}{b_2}$. Any further clues for the remaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We show $\frac{x+a_1}{y+b_1} - \frac{x+a_2}{y + b_2} \ge 0 $.
 \begin{align}
 &\frac{x+a_1}{y+b_1} - \frac{x+a_2}{y + b_2}  = \frac{x(b_2 - b_1) + y(a_1 - a_2) + a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1 }{(y+b_1)(y+b_2)} \nonumber\\
 &\ge  \frac{x(b_2 - b_1) + y(a_1 - a_2) }{(y+b_1)(y+b_2)}
 \end{align}
 We complete the proof  showing $x(b_2 - b_1) \ge   - y(a_1 - a_2)$.
 \begin{align}
 \frac{x}{y} + \frac{a_1 - a_2}{b_2 - b_1} \ge   \frac{a_1}{b_1} + \frac{a_1 - a_2}{b_2 - b_1} = \frac{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}{b_1 ( b_2 - b_1)} \ge 0
 \end{align}